# How do I use the Element API to search via entry title?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I can't seem to find this anywhere. Thanks.

**Update:**

```
'api/entry/search.json' => function() {
    return [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'search' => (craft()->request->getParam('search')) ? craft()->request->getParam('search') : '' 
        ],
        'first' => true,
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            return [
                'title' => $entry->title,
                'url' => $entry->url,
            ];
        },
    ];
},
```

Using the url: `api/entry/search.json?search=title:test` did not work.

---

This code works, but the title needs to be exact:

```
'api/entry/search.json' => function() {
    return [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'title' => craft()->request->getParam('title')
        ],
        'first' => true,
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            return [
                'title' => $entry->title,
                'url' => $entry->url,
            ];
        },
    ];
},
```

Using this url: `api/entry/search.json?title=Test%20Article`, works, but not `api/entry/search.json?title=Test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is an example of using the search feature in a GET request with parameter 'search'.

```
return [
    'elementType' => 'Entry',
    'criteria' => ['search' => (craft()->request->getParam('search')) ? 'title:'.craft()->request->getParam('search') : '' ],
    'paginate' => true,
    'elementsPerPage' => 10,
    'pageParam' => 'pg',
    'transformer' => new ListTransformer(),
];`
```

I assume you can use this instead of the custom transformer class that is being used in the above example:

```
'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
    return [
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'url' => $entry->url,
        'summary' => $entry->summary,
        'body' => $entry->body,
    ];
},
```

Comment: How would I use this in the URL? Like this: `search.json?search=title:test` ?

Comment: URL format is correct I haven't delved too deeply into search syntax for parameters like title:test
mine is search.json?search=test that is global search

Comment: The syntax for search=title:test is correct

Comment: Hmm, ok. Doesn't seem to fetch anything. I will tinker with it. Thanks.

Comment: Try this
`title:"*test*"`

Comment: Negative, I updated with two different approaches I tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40609/discussion-between-green-plastic-and-mark-watson).